# $var not greater than and not lesser than character length

Tags: php, if-statement

Can't seem to get this to work. What Im trying to achieve is check if the variable isn't longer than 68, but also not shorter than 64.

However, I can't seem to achieve even that...can someone please point out what I'm doing wrong?

Also, is there a way to simplify this procedure?

```
if (!strlen($pre_session_key_1) > 68) {
    if (!strlen($pre_session_key_1) < 64) {
        ......
    }
}
```

Thanks and please be kind newb here,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
if (!(strlen($pre_session_key_1) > 68)) {
        if (!(strlen($pre_session_key_1) < 64)) {
            ......
    }
}
```

Or better yet:

```
if ((strlen($pre_session_key_1) <= 68) &&
    (strlen($pre_session_key_1) >= 64))
{
    ......
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
!strlen($pre_session_key_1) > 68) 
^----
```

you're doing `(Not length of string) > 68`

You should realize that `Not greater` is basically the same as `less than or equal to`, so your `!>` should be `<=`.

Answer (score 0):

you could try something like this

```
$valid=strlen( $pre_session_key_1 )>=64 && strlen( $pre_session_key_1 )<=68;
if( $valid ){ /* do stuff */ }
```